# How can I serve static html from spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I ran the spring-boot-sample-web-static project from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.5.x), made this alteration to the pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And added this class to serve a duplicate page index2.html from the same `static` folder location:

```java
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Rester {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rand", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    private RandomObj jsonEndpoint() {
        return new RandomObj();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/tw")
    public String somePg() {
        return "index2";
    }
}
```

The json url works fine, but when I try to access localhost:8080/tw I get a blank page, and this error in the console:

```
2017-02-22 15:37:22.076 ERROR 21494 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/tw] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you don't really need tomcat dependency, spring starter web & thymeleaf should do it.

Comment: `thymeloaf` is not needed. Just put `index.html` in `src/main/resources/static/` folder and static html is done!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Static files should be served from resources, not from a controller.

> Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within
> any of the following directories:
>
> ```
> /META-INF/resources/  
> /resources/  
> /static/  
> /public/
> ```

refs:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: oh, ok so I saw that localhost:8080/index2.html is viewable from the browser actually, and there is no way to serve it from the controller ?

Comment: check my second ref link, or if u dont want to handle parameters:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27279742/3862022

Comment: I have to add spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf and only refer to files in the templates directory, I think I got it, thank you

Comment: thanks! I created the folders `resources/static`, put a `index.html` file and it just works!

Comment: where exactly should these directorys be? i hope src/main/resources is not served automatically

Comment: These dirs should be located in `src/main/resources`. `src/main/resources` is not served automatically.

Comment: I have my `app.properties` in resources and it doesn't serve it

Comment: @csenga any diff between `src/main/resources` and `src/main/resources`?

Answer (score 58):

In Spring boot, `/META-INF/resources/`, `/resources/`, `static/` and `public/` directories are available to serve static contents.

So you can create a `static/` or `public/` directory under `resources/` directory and put your static contents there. And they will be accessible by: `http://localhost:8080/your-file.ext`. (assuming the `server.port` is 8080)

You can customize these directories using `spring.resources.static-locations` in the `application.properties`.

For example:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/custom/
```

Now you can use `custom/` folder under `resources/` to serve static files.

This is also possible using Java config in Spring Boot 2:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/custom/");
    }
}
```

This confugration maps contents of `custom` directory to the `http://localhost:8080/static/**` url.

Comment: What if I want the file in the static folder to be returned by a Spring controller? Which path should I use in `new File()`?

Answer (score 12):

I am using `:: Spring Boot :: (v2.0.4.`[*`RELEASE`*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes)`) with Spring Framework 5`

> Spring Boot 2.0 requires Java 8 as a minimum version. Many existing APIs have been updated to take advantage of Java 8 features such as: default methods on interfaces, functional callbacks, and new APIs such as javax.time.

**Static Content**

By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called <kbd>/static</kbd> (or <kbd>/public</kbd> or <kbd>/resources</kbd> or <kbd>/META-INF/</kbd>resources) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so that you can modify that behavior by adding your own `WebMvcConfigurer` and overriding the `addResourceHandlers` method.

By default, resources are mapped on `/**` and located on `/static` directory.
But you can customize the static loactions programmatically inside our web context configuration class.

```java
@Configuration @EnableWebMvc
public class Static_ResourceHandler implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // When overriding default behavior, you need to add default(/) as well as added static paths(/webapp).

        // src/main/resources/static/...
        registry
            //.addResourceHandler("/**") // « /css/myStatic.css
            .addResourceHandler("/static/**") // « /static/css/myStatic.css
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/") // Default Static Loaction
            .setCachePeriod( 3600 )
            .resourceChain(true) // 4.1
            .addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver()) // 4.1
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver()); //4.1

        // src/main/resources/templates/static/...
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/templates/**") // « /templates/style.css
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/templates/static/");

        // Do not use the src/main/webapp/... directory if your application is packaged as a jar.
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webapp/**") // « /webapp/css/style.css
            .addResourceLocations("/");

        // File located on disk
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/system/files/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:///D:/");
    }
}
```

```java
http://localhost:8080/handlerPath/resource-path+name
                    /static         /css/myStatic.css
                    /webapp         /css/style.css
                    /templates      /style.css
```

*In Spring every request will go through the DispatcherServlet. To avoid Static file request through DispatcherServlet(Front contoller) we configure MVC [Static content](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content).*

As `@STEEL` said static resources should not go through Controller. `Thymleaf` is a ViewResolver which takes the view name form controller and adds `prefix` and `suffix` to View Layer.

Answer (score 3):

As it is written before, some folders (/META-INF/resources/, /resources/, /static/, /public/) serve static content by default, conroller misconfiguration can break this behaviour.

It is a common pitfall that people define the base url of a controller in the `@RestController` annotation, instead of the `@RequestMapping` annotation on the top of the controllers.

This is wrong:

```
@RestController("/api/base")
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping
    public String myPostMethod( ...) {
```

The above example will prevent you from opening the index.html. The Spring expects a POST method at the root, because the `myPostMethod` is mapped to the "/" path.

You have to use this instead:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/base")
public class MyController {

    @PostMapping
    public String myPostMethod( ...) {
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to add thymeleaf dependency to pom.xml. Without this dependency Spring boot didn't find static resources.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three kinds of url in Spring Boot:

1. relative to web application root: eg. `"/abc"`
2. relative to classpath: eg.  `"classpath:/abc"`
3. relative to file system: eg. `"file:/abc"`

Return to the subject, in Spring Boot, static resources in the following 4 url can be accessed via
`"http://localhost:8080/${context root}/${your static resources}"`.

```
classpath:/META-INF/resources
classpath:/resources
classpath:/static
classpath:/public
```

Answer (score -1):

You can quickly serve static content in JAVA Spring-boot App via `thymeleaf` (ref: [source](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-serving-web-content))

I assume you have already added Spring Boot plugin `apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'` and the necessary `buildscript`

Then go ahead and ADD **thymeleaf** to your `build.gradle` ==>

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Lets assume you have added **home.html** at `src/main/resources`
To serve this file, you will need to create a controller.

```
package com.ajinkya.th.controller;

  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

  @Controller
  public class HomePageController {

      @RequestMapping("/")
      public String homePage() {
        return "home";
      }

  }
```

Thats it ! Now restart your gradle server. `./gradlew bootRun`