# Serve Angular static content in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

My Angular application is developed independent from my Spring Boot application using the JSON web server. I want to deploy my Angular application to Spring Boot. So far, I have done build --prod and generated the dist folder and copied the content within the dist foldet to the resources folder in Spring Boot. Also I have added the resource-maven-plugin to pom.xml, but I keep getting 404 when trying to access angular static files. Am i missing something? Is it possible to serve Angular static content this way?

EDIT

Is it enough to have the dist folder inside the target/classes folder?

Comment: See the following tutorial, focus on the structure of where the .html, .js and .css files are: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-springboot-angularjs-bootstrap-springdata-j

Comment: check in this post [`how-can-i-serve-static-html-from-spring-boot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394600/5081877) it may help you.