# I am getting file does not exist exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, file-io

I'm setting up logic to write string to an html file

I tried reading details.html file placed in \src\main\resources\static\

```
File htmlTemplateFile = new File("details.html");
```

OR

```
File htmlTemplateFile = new File("\src\main\resources\static\details.html");
```

When I run this code, I am getting file not found exception , although the file is placed in \src\main\resources\static\

I have tried both above mentioned alternatives, still file not found exception is being thrown.

ERROR : msgjava.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'details.html' does not exist

Comment: You need either an absolute path (from root) or a relative path (from the execution context), neither of which you have. If you want to open it as a *resource* then you should do that, and the path would be relative to the classpath.

Comment: I'm exploring java as fresh, so sorry for the doubt But,
Where can I find my relative path? @Dave Newton

Comment: Try with `new File("static/details.html");` Everything under `/resources` is considered as classpath entries.

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within
>   any of the following directories:
>
> /META-INF/resources/
>   /resources/
>   /static/
>   /public/

From [How can I serve static html from spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393211/how-can-i-serve-static-html-from-spring-boot)

So the following works (tested):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {


        // index.html under /src/main/resources/static
        File file = new File("index.html");

        System.out.println(file.getName());

    }

}
```