# API Documentation with ReDoc and Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redoc

Could someone share some examples on how to implement API Documentation using ReDoc along with SpringBoot framework. It would be great help if someone knows some good examples with ReDoc + Springboot.

Comment: Refer this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-docs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a spring boot application enabling springdoc-openapi-ui [1] and then add a static html [2] as shown in [here](https://redoc.ly/docs/redoc/quickstart/html/)! by changing spec-url as http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs [3]

[1] : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation

[2] : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42393332/878710

[3] :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Redoc</title>
    <!-- needed for adaptive design -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--
    Redoc doesn't change outer page styles
    -->
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <redoc spec-url='http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs'></redoc>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to set the base URL in the spec-URL as it changes based on the environment

Comment: Set it relatively: "v3/api-docs".