# Spring-boot HTML resource not found

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am unable to access my static html files in spring boot. I tried different configurations but still I get the resource not found error

Firstly I tried using JSP,it did not work, then I switched to thymeleaf it did work that is because of JPS limitations and finally I used html.

My controllers were working fine I used **RestController** and **Controller** for seperate test runs they worked thymeleaf required **RequestMapping** to be declared at the class level to work but in case of html I was stuck and then I found this

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /resources/**
spring.web.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.web.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.favor-parameter=true
```

I was able to access the static resources but without controller , they did not work with the controller and I am getting resource not found error.

And for your kind information I tried placing the html files in **main/webapps/WEB-INF/**, **/resources/static/,/resources/templates/** and currently I am able to access them because they are in resources/static/ and I have an 404.html in /resources/public/error/404.html every time I use an endpoint I get the 404.html but the controllers are still not working

This is my controller

```
@Controller
public class AssignmentController {

    @GetMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("login")
    public String myLogin() {
        return "login";
    }         
}
```

And to be clear the url that works is http://localhost:8080/index.html/  which should be entered manually but when I use [http://localhost:8080/home, http://localhost:8080/](http://localhost:8080/index.html/)index, or [http://localhost:8080/](http://localhost:8080/index.html/) I get the error page

And my last attempt was using webmvcconfigurer

```
     @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/resources/**/");
            resourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
            registry.viewResolver(resourceViewResolver);
        }
```

Here is the log

```
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login', model {}
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/resources/**/login.html]
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/resources/**/login.html", parameters={}
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
 DEBUG 12920 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

I am using spring boot 3.1.5,
my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <groupId>com.sunbasedata.qa2</groupId>
    <artifactId>sunbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sunbase</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foodbox
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.sql.init.mode=NEVER
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

with a basic application like this the issue can be reproduce when you use  @Controller and place your html files in the resources/static/ folder

Comment: Could you gives a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I have edited the question and provided my pom as it was when I started working on it and the application.properties

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862637/3957754

Comment: If I follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862637/3957754 I am getting a Whitelabel Error Page 404

Comment: Is sharing a repo allowed I don't know here is the github link https://github.com/mohdabraralikhan/Springboot-app.git

Comment: Do you only  need to server a static file? like http://localhost:7060/foo.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a misconfiguration in your project. Serve static files are the most simple thing.

I tried your github sample (disabling the database because no body has your database) and the html files are available

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wwuA.png]

Anyway I show you a thymeleaf sample

### Thymeleaf

I started an old template with thymeleaf

https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-boot-templates/tree/master/013-thymeleaf-sqlite-crud

[image]

I added a foo.txt (../src/main/resources/static/foo.txt) in the static folder

[image]

After the restart the file is ready:

[image]

Comment: I just used a random database from other project, my mi focus was this issue thanks

Comment: If it helped you, don't forget mark as solved or useful